# The Error Bars and the value labels are not getting placed on the Correct Bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to add Error bars and label values to the graphs. I am able to add the bars. But they are not getting placed in the exact place which I want. That is each error bar and label value is not getting placed on its corresponding bar. Instead they are mismatched.

The code I used:

```
Source_Data <-
data.frame(
    key = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
    Product_Name = c(
      "Table",
      "Table",
      "Chair",
      "Table",
      "Bed",
      "Bed",
      "Sofa",
      "Chair",
      "Sofa"
    ),
    Product_desc = c("XX", "XXXX", "YY", "X", "Z", "ZZZ", "A", "Y", "A"),
    sd =c(0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.7,0.8,0.5),
    Cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

)

Source_Data %>% 
ggplot(aes(Product_Name, Cost)) + 
geom_col(aes(fill = Product_desc), position = position_dodge(preserve = 
"single")) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Cost-sd, ymax=Cost+sd)) +
geom_text(aes(label=Cost)) +
facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
theme(strip.placement = "outside") + 
theme_bw()
```

When the code is run I am not able to place the Error bars and the label values on the correct bars.

Also is there a way to make the graph more interactive? i.e. when i move my cursor over top of the graph the values should get automatically displayed, if required I am happy to post this as a separate question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better approach than I what I provide here, and/or this may not be exactly what you need. Please comment if this resembles what you are looking for.

I switched your code from `position_dodge` to `position_dodge2` which better centers groups of bars in x position. Also, moved `fill = Product_desc` to main `ggplot` call (good practice).

I consistently set `width` to .9 for `geom_col`, `geom_errorbar`, and `geom_text`. To get the errorbars to align, I added `padding` (see: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2251). Also, moved text y position to slightly above error bar (`Cost+sd` and `vjust` - could be considered elsewhere if preferred).

For interactivity, maybe consider `plotly` package. Please describe further exactly what you would like to see in `hover` behavior.

```
Source_Data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Product_Name, Cost, fill = Product_desc)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Cost-sd, ymax=Cost+sd), position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single", padding = .5)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Cost+sd, label=Cost), position = position_dodge2(width=.9), vjust = -1) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Bar plot with error bars and text aligned]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ben. This particular code is working fine for this Data. But when i try to run the same code for some other data. The error bars are getting mismatched. Is there any parameter which I need to Tweak according to the Data ? Can you please let me know which is the value to be tweaked.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look a bit later today. Just in case, if you can provide a picture (and add to your question above) of the error bars misplaced that might help. An alternative would be a sample of the data that causes the problem to reproduce.

Comment: I've done a few different iterations and sometimes the numbers are displaced, but the errorbars seem to align ok for me. Are you able to add an image or data sample that reproduces the problem in your question?

Comment: Thanks For the help :) and I apologies for being very late on this.

Comment: For interactivity is there any way to convert the above graph to plotly without using ggplotly. When i am using ggplotly its creating issues with axis and size of the plots. The same ggplot can you help me in converting it to plot_ly. ? I have requested a question for this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294613/how-to-convert-a-ggplot-to-plot-ly) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just adding bits and pieces to your script and making it less verbose. You may not need the text on the bar since one can see that from the `y-axis'.

```
library(ggplot2)
# saving the min and max values on variables for the errorbar 
min <- Source_Data$Cost - Source_Data$sd
max <- Source_Data$Cost + Source_Data$sd

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Plotting the base layer and saving it on base
base <- ggplot(Source_Data, aes(Product_Name, Cost, fill = Product_desc))

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# adding the bar and error bar on the base layer and saving it on base_col_err_bar

base_col_err_bar <- base + 
geom_col(position = "dodge2") + 
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), 
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5, padding = 0.5)
  )

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Adding the text and facet layer and the themes you wanted
b_facet_text <- base_col_err_bar + 
geom_text(aes(label=Cost)) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") + 
  theme_bw() 

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Renaming the x and y labs and the legend title

b_facet_text+ labs(x = "Product Name", y = "Cost", fill = "Product Desc.")
```

## output

[image: error_bar_out]

If you really want to tweak the position of the `geom_text()` (IMHO, you don't need 'em in the first place), read the manual using `?geom_text' from R.